# Not same hash SHA256 SQL Server/PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, hash, sha256, sha

I have an SQL Server database, and I want to start session in PHP for users.
I can interact with my database, but I have some problem with SQL Server hash.

I use Primavera for create user+password so the password is hashed and generated automatically by Primavera. I want to create an application with PHP, and I need to start session with these user+password informations.

(Primavera is an application which create the database on SQL Server)

For users I can see the password like this:

> SHA-256:CB4F6845EDF88E23:2710:9FFB6G

And with PHP

```
echo hash("SHA256","*thepass*")."<br>";
```

I have this:

> 76f7e6226e348ac43e2566ef1(...)

So I can't start session.

Comment: Hello, nobody know how I can connect on my SQL Server databse ?

Comment: 1) Please post the text from that screen shot as text, rather than a tiny image. 2) Where did that text come from / what generated it? You can tell that it's not just a SHA256 hash, because it contains multiple sections separated with `:`, whereas a plain hashing function would just contain a string of hexadecimal digits. 3) What exactly are you trying to log into, and how? It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. [Note: please [edit] the question with further details, don't try to post them as comments.]

Comment: I use Primavera for create user+password so the password is hashed  et generatec automatically by Primavera. I want to create an application with PHP, and I need to start session with these user+password informations

Comment: Then it sounds like your question is about how Primavera (which I'm afraid I've never heard of) generates and formats password hashes? I'm still not entirely sure what this has to do with SQL Server; is Primavera an authentication layer for SQL Server? Can you show us the code that tries to "start the session", rather than just an `echo`? And again, *please add the hash from that screenshot as text*; it's only one line, it's not like it will take up loads of space in the question.

Comment: Primavera is an application which create the database on SQL Server. I can't see how he formats password hashes... My code is like "$sql = "select * from user where username=... ans password=..."

Comment: I know nothing about Primavera but no sane password hashing system would use a raw SHA hash (google for "rainbow tables"). I suspect it's at least using a salt. You cannot replicate the system in some other language unless you know how it works.

Comment: OK, so the password is not for SQL Server itself, but for some application which happens to store its passwords in SQL Server? As I mentioned in my earlier comment, this is clearly more than just a hash, probably it includes the salt to use, and maybe some other parameters. The application presumably has some function for verifying if a particular raw password matches the stored value, based on reading back those parameters.

Comment: OK thank you. So I need to create 2 new tables on my databses for user authentification for my PHP application ? (user rights and user table)